# angular-auth-oidc-client -Not able to use latest token that Identity server is sending

Tags: angular, openid-connect

identity/authorization server is sending refreshed/latest token in response but somehow my angular application not able to utilize that token

I have angular application that call a REST API endpint . REST ENDPOINT is protected by bearer token .

**The flow is as below**

1. Logged in my application and I got bearer token in respsonse and
   called rest api from angular application using bearer token
2. after 5 minute silent renew get fired and called authentication/autherization server and in response got latest token
3. after 5 mint again silent renew get fired (now it is total 10 mint from login time begging) and called authentication/autherization server and in response got latest token but now when Angular
   application call rest api it come unauthorized call to api .

**Note** - What I have observed that in local storage under browser it keep very first token ( I mean login time response token)

**My code is as below**

**app.module.ts file**

```
export function configureAuth(oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
return () =>
oidcConfigService.withConfig({
stsServer: environment.stsServer,
redirectUrl: ${window.location.origin}/,
clientId: '<<client id >>',
scope: 'openid profile email <priviledge>',
responseType: 'id_token token',
triggerAuthorizationResultEvent: false,
postLogoutRedirectUri: ${window.location.origin}/unauthorized,
startCheckSession: true,
silentRenew: true,
silentRenewUrl: ${window.location.origin}/silent-renew.html,
postLoginRoute: '/',
forbiddenRoute: '/forbidden',
unauthorizedRoute: '/unauthorized',
historyCleanupOff: true,
autoUserinfo: false,
storage: localStorage
}
);
```

**providers**: [

```
OidcConfigService,
{
provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
useFactory: configureAuth,
deps: [OidcConfigService],
multi: true,
},
```

**silent-renew.html**

```
<script> window.onload = function () 
{ 
   /* The parent window hosts the Angular application */ 
   var parent = window.parent; 
   var event = new CustomEvent('oidc-silent-renew-message', { detail: window.location }); 
   parent.dispatchEvent(event); 
 }; 
</script>
```

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets",
"src/silent-renew.html",
```

**oidc-client version**

```
"angular-auth-oidc-client": "^11.6.0",
```

Any help on this will be really appreciated